# Why doesn't this WPF code generate a context menu?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, brushes

Perhaps I'm having a [Post-Ballmer-Peak Moment](http://xkcd.com/323). 
I'm hoping that someone can help point out the obvious to me.

Why does this code generate a context menu on right click:

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent">
  <Canvas.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <TextBlock>WTF?</TextBlock>
    </ContextMenu>
  </Canvas.ContextMenu>
</Canvas>
```

And this code doesn't generate a context menu:

```
<Canvas>
  <Canvas.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <TextBlock>WTF?</TextBlock>
    </ContextMenu>
  </Canvas.ContextMenu>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: WTF, indeed.  I thought you were crazy at first, but I got the same result.  WPF baffles me sometimes also. Hopefully, there is some sane reason for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because the `Transparent` brush allows an area to be hittable and thus receive and respond to mouse clicks, whereas the default `null` brush doesn't. In other words, without any brush defined, the region becomes "hollow" and clicks pass through; with a brush defined (even a transparent one), they are "solid" and clicks can be received.

See this helpful article on **[WPF brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx)** for more info.

Comment: I retract my previous WTF statement.  That makes perfect sense. +1

Comment: That's really good to know, actually. And it actually makes sense why it does that.
Thanks

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help.

Comment: Just learning about the canvas, but this is a great description. concise and to the point. kudos good sir!